# How to extract text from a PDF file with Apache PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I would like to extract text from a given PDF file with Apache PDFBox.

I wrote this code:

```
PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = null;
PDDocument pdDoc = null;
COSDocument cosDoc = null;
File file = new File(filepath);

PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(file));
parser.parse();
cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
pdfStripper.setStartPage(1);
pdfStripper.setEndPage(5);
String parsedText = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
System.out.println(parsedText);
```

However, I got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.fontbox.afm.AFMParser.main(AFMParser.java:304)
```

I added pdfbox-1.8.5.jar and fontbox-1.8.5.jar to the class path.

**Edit**

I added `System.out.println("program starts");` to the beginning of the program.

I ran it, then I got the same error as mentioned above and `program starts` did not appear in the console.

Thus, I think I have a problem with the class path or something.

Thank you.

Comment: Probably your PDF file is not completely valid and makes PDFBox stumble. You might want to supply the PDF for inspection.

Comment: Are you sure you start the correct `main()` method? The exception looks like you start the `main()` of `org.apache.fontbox.afm.AFMParser` which looks like PDFBox code, not your code.

Comment: You're right. I reset the run configuration and now the program works. Thank you very much, mkl.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I executed your code and it worked properly. Maybe your problem is related to `FilePath` that you have given to file. I put my pdf in C drive and hard coded the file path. Here is my code:

```
// PDFBox 2.0.8 require org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessRead
// import org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessFile;

public class PDFReader{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = null;
        PDDocument pdDoc = null;
        File file = new File("C:/my.pdf");
        PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(file));
        parser.parse();
        try (COSDocument cosDoc = parser.getDocument()) {
            pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
            pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
            pdfStripper.setStartPage(1);
            pdfStripper.setEndPage(5);
            String parsedText = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
            System.out.println(parsedText);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its working fine when we get pdf file from computer, But I am trying to get it from SD card in android then it giving error like "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.awt.print.Printable" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.geeklabs.pdfreader-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]"

Comment: And also getting  "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument" even though adding libs to build path

Comment: How is PDFbox used? I'm new to this concept but have no idea where to begin. I've downloaded the jar file but double clicking it doesnt work.

Comment: With pdfbox 2.0.5 this code does not compile with error: java.io.FileInputStream cannot be cast to org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessRead

Comment: The constructor PDFParser(FileInputStream) is undefined cast to org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessRead given error

Comment: This answer does not work with the current version of the library, see the answer by @Matthias

Comment: wrap with org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessBufferedFileInputStream

Answer (score 55):

Using [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) 2.0.7, this is how I get the text of a PDF:

```
static String getText(File pdfFile) throws IOException {
    PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(pdfFile);
    return new PDFTextStripper().getText(doc);
}
```

Call it like this:

```
try {
    String text = getText(new File("/home/me/test.pdf"));
    System.out.println("Text in PDF: " + text);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

Since user oivemaria asked in the comments:

You can use PDFBox in your application by adding it to your dependencies in `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
  compile group: 'org.apache.pdfbox', name: 'pdfbox', version: '2.0.7'
}
```

[Here's more](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html) on dependency management using Gradle.

---

If you want to keep the PDF's format in the parsed text, give [PDFLayoutTextStripper](https://github.com/JonathanLink/PDFLayoutTextStripper) a try.

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer. I used the same to get the resource as InputStream to load the file from `src\resources` folder. You can also use maven dependency from m2repo https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox

Comment: The PPDocument need to be closed after usage.

Answer (score 6):

[PdfBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) 2.0.3 has a command line tool as well.

1. Download jar file
2. `java -jar pdfbox-app-2.0.3.jar ExtractText [OPTIONS] <inputfile> [output-text-file]`

> ```
> Options:
>   -password  <password>        : Password to decrypt document
>   -encoding  <output encoding> : UTF-8 (default) or ISO-8859-1, UTF-16BE, UTF-16LE, etc.
>   -console                     : Send text to console instead of file
>   -html                        : Output in HTML format instead of raw text
>   -sort                        : Sort the text before writing
>   -ignoreBeads                 : Disables the separation by beads
>   -debug                       : Enables debug output about the time consumption of every stage
>   -startPage <number>          : The first page to start extraction(1 based)
>   -endPage <number>            : The last page to extract(inclusive)
>   <inputfile>                  : The PDF document to use
>   [output-text-file]           : The file to write the text to
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Maven dep:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then the fucntion to get the pdf text as String.

```
private static String readPDF(File pdf) throws InvalidPasswordException, IOException {
    try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(pdf)) {

        document.getClass();

        if (!document.isEncrypted()) {

            PDFTextStripperByArea stripper = new PDFTextStripperByArea();
            stripper.setSortByPosition(true);

            PDFTextStripper tStripper = new PDFTextStripper();

            String pdfFileInText = tStripper.getText(document);
            // System.out.println("Text:" + st);

            // split by whitespace
            String lines[] = pdfFileInText.split("\\r?\\n");
            List<String> pdfLines = new ArrayList<>();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (String line : lines) {
                System.out.println(line);
                pdfLines.add(line);
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works fine to extract data from a PDF file that has text content using pdfbox 2.0.6

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripperByArea;

public class PDFTextExtractor {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       System.out.println(readParaFromPDF("C:\\sample1.pdf",3, "Enter Start Text Here", "Enter Ending Text Here"));
    //Enter FilePath, Page Number, StartsWith, EndsWith
   }
   public static String readParaFromPDF(String pdfPath, int pageNo, String strStartIndentifier, String strEndIdentifier) {
       String returnString = "";
       try {
           PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(pdfPath));
           document.getClass();        
           if (!document.isEncrypted()) {
               PDFTextStripperByArea stripper = new PDFTextStripperByArea();
               stripper.setSortByPosition(true);
               PDFTextStripper tStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
               tStripper.setStartPage(pageNo);
               tStripper.setEndPage(pageNo);
               String pdfFileInText = tStripper.getText(document);
               String strStart = strStartIndentifier;
               String strEnd = strEndIdentifier;
               int startInddex = pdfFileInText.indexOf(strStart);
               int endInddex = pdfFileInText.indexOf(strEnd);
               returnString = pdfFileInText.substring(startInddex, endInddex) + strEnd;
           }
          } catch (Exception e) {
              returnString = "No ParaGraph Found";
       }
            return returnString;
   }
}
```